# How to use global component from a dependancy in Vue2

Tags: vue.js

I am using vue-form-generator and trying to get it to render a simple form without success. I am going to re-use this generator in dozens of files as my application is form heavy and would like to make this global and I'll just manage everything in components.

main.js file

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
import "./registerServiceWorker";
import VueFormGenerator from "vue-form-generator";

Vue.use("VueFormGenerator", VueFormGenerator);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

I have a larger template that uses this template for most of the page, this is the template file where I am trying to use `VueFormGenerator`

NewTrade.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
    <p class="introText">Please try to stick to your strategy and use the Manual mode as little as possible if at all! </p>
        <form action="#">
            <VueFormGenerator
                    :schema="schema"
                    :model="model"
            />
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>


export default {

  data() {
    return {
      model: {
        name: "David Johnson"
      },
      schema: {
        fields: [
          {
            name: "text"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is the error I get in Chrome.

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <VueFormGenerator> - did you register 
the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the 
"name" option.

found in

---> <NewTrade> at src/components/NewTrade.vue
   <Trading> at src/components/Trading.vue
     <App> at src/App.vue
       <Root>
```

Comment: To register a component do `Vue.component`

Comment: Try `<vue-form-generator>` instead of  `<VueFormGenerator>`

Comment: @Trouble are you saying in the component? I tried that and I get `vue is not defined` in the chrome console.

Comment: no, In the main.js

Comment: @Trouble I get this error when I do that. ``[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <VueFormGenerator>
       <NewTrade> at src/components/NewTrade.vue
         <Trading> at src/components/Trading.vue
           <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>
warn @ webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:588``

I put the line under all of the Vue.use

Answer (score 0):

just use `component` instead of `use`

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
import "./registerServiceWorker";
import VueFormGenerator from "vue-form-generator";

Vue.component("VueFormGenerator ", VueFormGenerator);  // <-- component instead of use
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Usually you'd use `vue-form-generator` instead of `VueFormGenerator` as the component name here and in template, as that's the convention, but you only need that when you compile run-time.

here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/o77lmqq9v6

Comment: I did that and got this error `vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:587 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <VueFormGenerator>
       <NewTrade> at src/components/NewTrade.vue
         <Trading> at src/components/Trading.vue
           <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>`

Comment: I did that. Just double checked.

Comment: I have it like that, I wonder if it has to do something with the fact that its separate files.

Comment: it may be. Your error is consistent with the component not having a `<template>` block or a render function. (Try removing template from HelloWorld component in example)

Comment: HelloWorld is another route it wouldn't impact this and I'm not sure where to go next.

Comment: HelloWorld is a component, the example has no routes